# How to create django-cms page executing a command from a cms_plugin?

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, backend, django-cms

The idea is that from a plugin you have to give name and link, then the plugin will create a new page with title as name, set is published = true, select a default template and leave the other fields blank.

The closest info I found is in https://gist.github.com/894776 but i don't get this line

> > from gamesradar.apps.cms_override.api import create_page, add_plugin
> >     Where did that came from?

Also if there is an easiest way to do this is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since django CMS 2.2 there is a Python API to create CMS objects (Pages, Titles, Plugins).

Please refer to http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3/extending_cms/api_references.html#cms-api for docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
from cms.api import create_page

data = {
    'title': 'HOME', 'template': 'home.html', 
    'language': 'en','reverse_id': 'home', 'published': True,
    'created_by': 'db-initialization'
}
create_page(**data)
```